# silder control or number

Tags: html, input, slider

I was searching for answer for this question

You are developing an HTML5 web form to collect feedback information from site visitors. The web form must display an INPUT element that meets the following requirements:

- Allow numeric values between 1 and 10.
- Default to the value of 5.
- Display as a slider control on the page. You need to add the INPUT
  element to the form.

Which HTML element should you add?

```
<input type="number" name="rating" min ="1" max-"10">

<input type="number" name="rating" min="1" max="10" default="5">
<input type="range" name="rating" min="0" max="10" default"="5">
<input type="range" name="rating" min="10" max="10" value="5">
```

Shouldn’t the answer be this one.

```
<input type="range" name="rating" min="0" max="10" default"="5">
```

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a lot of confusion regarding this question.
Let's break down the requirements:

- Allow numeric values between 1 and 10 : `type="number" min="1" max="10"`
- Default to the value of 5 : This is defaulted by `value = 5`
- Display as a slider control on the page : `input type="range"`

As you can see, `numeric` and `slider` are conflicting with each other. You can have a slider or you can have a numeric input box, not both.

I would assume that the question is asking for a slider, and so the `value="5"` field would put the slider in the middle.

The answer is

```
    <input type="range" name="rating" min="10" max="10" value="5">
```

(there is a typo for `min="10"`, should be `min="1"` but this is the correct answer for this question).

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer, it is instead an explanation of the question, why did you post it as an answer?

Comment: I have edited my response to show the correct answer, cheers!